# animate rotation of child to face camera not giving expected results three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rotation

I have the following scenario:

A parent that can be at any point in world space can have any amount of rotation and uniform scale.

Inside of this parent i have a child that is always at 0,0,0 (local coordinates) this child is not rotated relative to the parent or scaled.

At some point i want to rotate this child around its y-axis inside of the parent so its x-axis faces the camera.

currently i do this in the following manner:

```
let rotation = {v: 0};
const goal = Math.atan2( ( this.sceneManager.camera.position.x - this.sceneManager.carContainer.position.x ), ( this.sceneManager.camera.position.z - this.sceneManager.carContainer.position.z ) ) + .5 * Math.PI;
const mapRotation = new TWEEN.Tween(rotation)
    .delay(750)
    .to({ v: goal }, 250)
    .onUpdate(() => {
        animation.model.rotation.y = rotation.v;
    });
mapRotation.start();
```

In this case `animation.model` is the child
`this.sceneManager.carContainer` is the parent
and `this.sceneManager.camera` is the point i want the child to rotate towards.

When this code is run the child does rotate about +- 90 degrees but never ends up facing the camera. And i am very confused to why it is not working.

Both the parent and camera have positions in world space and can be at any point in the world.

If more information, context or code is needed please let me know!

Comment: My best guess is because you're calculating the angle, but then adding ` + .5 * Math.PI;` for some reason. If removing those two values doesn't fix your problem, could you post a working demo? Maybe via [a snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or a JSFiddle.